# Populating a JList with multiplte Views

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have the following problem:
I want to populate several JLists with the class "Worker". In the Worker Class, there is a field of WorkerType (an Enum). The ListModel for each View should be the same Type and same Instance, so that when a Worker gets deleted in one View it shouldn't be visible in the other Views anymore. Is this possible?

Comment: what I forgot to say: 
the different views of the JList should only show specific Worker Types.

Comment: @Joey Rohan: and how ?

Comment: Please show us some work, and if possible, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to use a single column JTable. A JTable supports filtering, so each view can be created to show only a specific worker type.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more information.